# Make elements that behave like anchor tags?

Tags: html, anchor, element

I was wondering, can you make an element that is not an anchor (`<a>`) tag (for ex. `<div>`, `<span>`, etc.) behave like an anchor tag? (Link to page on click).

Or, are there any other elements that behave the same?

Comment: Why not just use `<a>`? Although that is possible

Comment: Just wondering @Swellar

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is SO not a place for curiosity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only partially.

- You can give any tag a `tabindex` to make it focusable.
- You can give any tag a `click` event listener that sets `location.href`.
- You can't make anything other than a real link react to `:link` and `:visited` in CSS

That leaves aside issues of getting (for example) screen readers to recognise the element as a link and annouce it to the user, and for search engines to recognize it as a link and follow it, and [the JS simply failing](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

---

In short: If you want a link, then use a real link. HTML is a semantic markup language. Use the semantics it comes with. Don't try to fake the behaviour that comes with the semantics using other elements.